# how to restructuring entirely data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have a complicated data of province , city , zone and I want to restruct it entirely in Reactjs

my data is like this:

```
{
id: 1
zone: "zoneName1"
city_id:{
   city: "cityName1"
   id: 1
   province_id:{
      province: "provinceName1"
      id: 1
      }
   }
}
{
id: 2
zone: "zoneName2"
city_id:{
   city: "cityName1"
   id: 1
   province_id:{
      province: "provinceName1"
      id: 1
      }
   }
}
...
```

I want to be sure that every zone will be in correct city and every city be in correct province
I want to get into data and sort it exactly like bellow
and I want to sort these data like this:

```
{
provinceName1:{
   cityName1:{
      zoneName:zoneName1 ,
      zoneId:1
      }
   }
},
{
provinceName1:{
   cityName1:{
      zoneName:zoneName2 ,
      zoneId:2
      }
   }
},
...
```

my current code is:

```
export const addressDataCleaner=(data)=>{
  let provinceObject ={}
  for (let item of data) {
    let province= item.city_id.province_id.province
    provinceObject = {...provinceObject, [province] : {}}
  }
  let provinceObjectWithCity = {}
  for (let item0 in provinceObject) {
    for(let item1 of data) {
      if (item0 === item1.city_id.province_id.province) {
        provinceObjectWithCity = {
          ...provinceObjectWithCity, 
          [item0]: {
            ...provinceObjectWithCity[item0],
            [item1.city_id.city] : []
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
return provinceObjectWithCity
}
```

and it returns this:

```
province1:{
   city1: {}
   city2: {}
   }
province2:{
   city3: {}
   city4: {}
   }
```

clearly I am restructuring entirely my data that got from server with **for** and **if** and trying to recognize which zone and city is for which province and creat it how I want to use in my website

I will be really thankful if you can help me

Comment: You're asking the same question without improving. [old Question asked today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799128/sort-complicated-data-in-react).

Comment: @decpk can you see that question? because it tells me it is closed!!

Comment: You can convert to array and use HOF or you can directly map and convert the data output accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  zone: "zoneName1",
  city_id:{
   city: "cityName1",
   id: 1,
   province_id:{
      province: "provinceName1",
      id: 1
   }
  }
},
{
id: 2,
zone: "zoneName2",
city_id:{
   city: "cityName1",
   id: 1,
   province_id:{
      province: "provinceName1",
      id: 1
      }
   }
}];

const addressDataCleaner = data => {
  return data.map(item => {
    return {
      [item.city_id.province_id.province]: {
        [item.city_id.city]: {
          zoneName: item.zone,
          zoneId: item.id,
        },
      },
    };
  });
};

const res = addressDataCleaner(data);
console.log(res);
```